# How to deliever an image file with PHP?

Tags: php

I have a img tag as

```
<img src="http://######/index.php?option=com_payplans&view=cron" alt="."/>
```

But src is not a path of image. This url executes a php script. I want show an image intead of alternate text of broken image. I am using Google Chrome.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague.  How are we supposed to know what's at /index.php ?  PHP files can be used to generate images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution by adding following code in my script

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
echo file_get_contents(PATH_TO_IMAGE');
```

Answer (score 3):

So modify your PHP script to echo an image.

e.g.

```
header('Content-type: image/jpg');
readfile('/path/to/file.jpg');
```

Comment: that what I am asking, how to display image in script?

Answer (score 1):

The PHP script must return an image.
How does your index.php look like?

It should be

```
Header("image/png");
// Dump image data here
```

Also try calling http://######/index.php?option=com_payplans&view=cron in a browser to see if any error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if the server response is okay. It should response with a valid content type and valid binary content.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw an image using gd library

read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreate.php)